# get_posts() doesn't return posts when looking for a certain post_type

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have the same args to look for a certain post:

```
$page = 0;

$args = array(
    "posts_per_page" => 10,
    "offset" => $page * 10,
    "post_type" => "graven",
    "post_status" => "publish"
);

$posts = get_posts($args);
var_dump($posts);
```

This properly returns the 10 first posts of this type, ordered by date. Now, there's another custom post type (made using the Pods framework, pods.io), which has a different name, other than that, should be quite the same. The only difference I should be using in my queries is changing the `post_type` to `begraafplaats` and set the `post_status` to `draft`, however, this results in an empty array to be returned. I know the ID of one of these posts, so using `get_post(<the id>)` I queried the post, and got the result as I expected.

This gives me the following output:

```
WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] => 3935
    [post_author] => 1
    [post_date] => 2015-08-21 04:25:16
    [post_date_gmt] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [post_content] => 
    [post_title] => R.K. Begraafplaats St. Theresiakerk (Eindhoven)
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => draft
    [comment_status] => closed
    [ping_status] => closed
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] => 
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 2015-08-21 04:25:16
    [post_modified_gmt] => 2015-08-21 04:25:16
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 0
    [guid] => http://example.com/?post_type=begraafplaats&p=3935
    [menu_order] => 0
    [post_type] => begraafplaats
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
    [filter] => raw
)
```

As you can see, the post_type returned is the same I used in my `$args` array, and the post type is draft, as expected. Yet, it doesn't seem to get me any results.

Would there be a reasonable explanation of why this wouldn't work?

Comment: There could be an error in the code, a typo, but you are only showing the code that does work. It could be possible the custom post type is not registered yet when you perform the query. Use `<?php post_type_exists( $post_type ); ?>` to check that.

Comment: When retrieving all posts types using `get_post_types()`, the type `begraafplaats` is also returned properly. I don't think this is the case

Comment: According to this page http://pods.io/tutorials/using-pods-pages-advanced-content-types/ you can't use `get_posts()`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue using bare MySQL queries using `$wpdb`. It's not an elegant solution, however, I do have all the info I need now.

Comment: you should have provided the 'pods' way of handling things